# Querying JSON with JSON .NET

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, json.net

```
{
   "kind": "folderTree",
   "data":
   [
       {
           "id": "IEAAALNZI7777777",
           "title": "Root",
           "childIds":
           [
               "IEAAALNZI4ADAKBQ",
               "IEAAALNZI4ADAMBQ",
               "IEAAALNZI4ADAMBR"
           ],
           "scope": "WsRoot"
       },
       {
           "id": "IEAAANE7I7777777",
           "title": "Root",
           "childIds":
           [
               "IEAAANE7I4AC2NTX"
           ],
           "scope": "WsRoot"
       },
       {
           "id": "IEAAALNZI7777776",
           "title": "Recycle Bin",
           "childIds":
           [
               "IEAAALNZI4ADALZ2",
               "IEAAALNZI4ADAL52",
               "IEAAALNZI4ADALR3"
           ],
           "scope": "RbRoot"
       }
   ]
}
```

Im trying to query the following json structure, searching the child items I want to return the id for a given title.

I am trying something like this:

```
var folder = json["data"].Children().Where(x => x["Title"] == "Root");
```

But I'm not sure of the correct syntax

Comment: Why not deserialise it and use normal Linq?

Comment: Thanks, can I de-serialise into an anonymous object? If so how do I query this.

Comment: The title suggests this was already serialised, don't you have the actual classes this came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to query [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) objects.  It supports [JSONPath query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) including wildcards.  You can then further narrow down the search with a [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clause:

```
var folders = json.SelectTokens("data[*]").Where(t => (string)t["title"] == "Root").ToList();
```

It also supports filtering of array entries based on property values if you don't want the extra `Where` clause:

```
var folders = json.SelectTokens("data[?(@.title == 'Root')]").ToList();
```

Both of the above do the same thing.  Incidentally, you've got two folders whose title is "Root" in your JSON, so your query will return multiple results.